# Clear varnish cache for a specific node

Tags: proxies

I am populating one of the node fields making third party api call. Since the data from api is supposed to change frequently mainly on node view. My question is, is it possible to clear caching for a specific node in varnish.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215617/how-to-send-a-purge-request-in-varnish should help

Comment: Are you using the Varnish integration module? https://drupal.org/project/varnish

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [Varnish HTTP Accelerator Integration](https://drupal.org/project/varnish) module, you can use the varnish_expire_cache() function, that accepts specifics paths like nodes or could be for other paths too.